# Automatic id generation

Tags: java

Any one have idea how to generate `id` starting from 1 so that the next object has 2 and so on?

I have trying the following but dose not work:

```
class students{

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public student(String name){
        this.id=id++;
        this.name
    }
}
```

Comment: private int id; change this to static int id ; and then try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a *static* class member to keep track of the last-used index. Be sure to also implement a copy constructor:

```
class students
{
    private static int next_id = 0;   // <-- static, class-wide counter

    private int id;                   // <-- per-object ID

    private String name;

    public students(String name)
    {
        this.id = ++students.next_id;
        this.name = name;

        // ...
    }

    public students(students rhs)
    {
        this.id = ++students.next_id;
        this.name = rhs.name;

        // ...
    }

    public static void reset_counter(int n)  // use with care!
    {
        students.next_id = n;
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

*Update:* As @JordanWhite suggest, you might like to make the static counter *atomic*, which means that it will be safe to use concurrently (i.e. in multiple threads at once). To that end, change the type to:

```
private static AtomicInteger next_id = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

The increment-and-read operation and the reset operation become:

```
this.id = students.next_id.incrementAndGet();  // like "++next_id"

students.next_id.set(n);                       // like "next_id = n"
```

Comment: @Icarus: No, that was just me being very confused. Java isn't my every-day language :-(

Comment: can you clarify it more, why this-> is not this.

Comment: why there are two constructors ??

Comment: @user1621585: One default, one copy constructor. I'll edit it to make it closer to your original case, but just make sure you understand that objects can be *copied*: `students s2 = new students(s1);` etc.

Comment: however, the problem when you write the all students information to binary file. and you enter new student it begins 1 so duplicate.!!!

Comment: @user1621585: feel free to add a function to reset the counter. You just have to be careful to ensure global uniqueness.

Comment: @user1621585: I've added an example function, but serialization is a whole different topic. You'd have to deserialize everything from disk first and keep track of the maximum ID, and then set the `next_id` to that value before starting to create further objects.

Comment: I have deserialize every thins and when I try to add a new student return back to 1.

Comment: how can assign the last number of id to the nextid when deserliazable

Comment: I would recommend using an AtomicInteger as the static object to keep track of the current id. If you use a regular integer in this class and at some point implement this object in a multi-threaded environment you may end up getting two different objects with the same id. I have submitted an edit request to reflect this change.

Comment: Hi  Kerrek SB, could you help me how to insert the function you talked about and how to use it. I mean the function to assign the last id of customer to next_id when I retrieve the information of customers from binary file.

Comment: @JordanWhite: I appreciate your input, but please don't just edit such a change in yourself. I'm happy to add it if you leave a comment to that end.

Comment: @user1621585: After you've deserialized everything, and kept track of the largest observed ID, just call `students.reset_counter(largestObservedID);` before you make any new objects.

Answer (score 4):

### Beware, using a static variable to keep track of your counter works in a very limited circumstance.

You can't run this code on more than one machine e.g. a web cluster if it's a web application. Also, the static variable is transient and will reset when you restart your application.

A common solution to generating a sequential id is to use a database. Most databases have a built-in way do this. For example, `IDENTITY` in SQL Server or `AUTO_INCREMENT` in MySQL.

Consider using a persistence framework like Hibernate and you can declare one of many proven strategies like [identity, hilo or uuid](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id) some of which are sequential and some aren't. Some are generated by the application and some by the database but the trade-offs are well documented and you'll know what you're getting yourself into.

Comment: I just used binary file to store and when I try to create new student, the id will start from 1.

Comment: You need to seed your static variable each time you load your app.

Answer (score 0):

you should chanage `private int id;` to `private static int id;` and `id++` to `++id`.

you can try:

```
class Students{
    private static int id;
    private String name;
    public Students(String name){
    this.id=++id; // this.id +=1；may be better 
    System.out.println(this.id);
    this.name = name;
   }
}
```

TestCode:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Students s1 = new Students("Mark1");
    Students s2 = new Students("Mark2");
}
```

}

Comment: How does that assign a **different** ID to each object?

Comment: @KerrekSB can't?  Please try it and think more before you vote down.

Comment: it works, but when I write the information to file and retrieve it all students id are 0

Comment: yes, you are increasing the value of `static` variable `id`, but how are you assigning it to new objects? or how does a new object know what id it is? If a new object is created, the value of id increases and since the actual older object doesn't have any mechanism to store `id` and that both the objects share the same id, `id` is no way unique

Comment: by adding a `private` variable, (not `static`) so that every object has a place to store its id, like making `id`
 `private int id;` and creating another `static` variable to keep track of ids `private static int id_next;`

Comment: anyway, this isn't the right answer, @kerrekSB's answer is correct