# Automatically initializing an int messageID in a constructor

Tags: java, constructor, final

How can I initialize a final int in the constructor in Java to be with 1 bigger than the previous instance and can I do that at all? I mean i have a `final int messageID;` which must be unique for every instance, how can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Final variable manipulation in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249917/final-variable-manipulation-in-java)

Comment: you need something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3478862/821057

Comment: possible duplicate of [how many instances for a class exists at runtime in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478795/how-many-instances-for-a-class-exists-at-runtime-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336030/automatic-id-generation

Answer (score 5):

Keep a

```
private static final AtomicInteger NEXT_MESSAGE_ID = new AtomicInteger();
```

Then in your constructor do

```
this.messageId = NEXT_MESSAGE_ID.getAndIncrement();
```

Comment: Thank you! But is there a different way to do that?

Comment: Why do you want a different way?

Comment: My university professor does not allow us to use things we have not learnt yet.. It's a bit silly, I know...

Comment: Then you have to go with the other proposed answer, although it is not threadsafe.

Answer (score 0):

A soulution could be to use a static variable to hold the largest message ID, then increment it each time a new object is created.

```
class Foo {
    static int maxMessageID = 0;
    final int messageID;

    public Foo() {
        this.messageID = ++maxMessageID;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

To make this thread safe, put the incrementing of the variable inside a method using `synchronized`.

```
class Foo {
    static int maxMessageID = 0;
    final int messageID;

    public Foo() {
        this.messageID = this.getID();
    }

   private synchronized int getID() {
       return ++maxMessageID;
   }
}
```

Comment: @assylias That is true. I just wanted to show how it can be done using simple techniques.