# Java auto increment id

Tags: java

I am doing some coding in Java, but it doesn't work:

```
public class job
{
   private static int count = 0; 
   private int jobID;
   private String name;
   private boolean isFilled;

   public Job(, String title, ){
      name = title;
      isFilled = false;
      jobID = ++count; 
  }
}
```

I need to auto-increment the Id when a new entry is created.

Comment: You're already doing this, by the way, please remove commas around `String title`

Comment: if you are creating multiple job objects, then keep track of the job_id outside the class (gives you job_1, job_2, etc)

Comment: @JattnetBorn2Code would be fine after you make it compilable.

Comment: think it will work (if you habe not more than 2million jobs) and correct to constructor to make it compilable.

Comment: looking at your Job constructor, i don't think it will even compile..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336030/automatic-id-generation

Comment: *"give a reason for downvote"* - "It does not work" does not help us understand what your problem is.  It is like going to a doctor and saying "I'm not feeling well" ... and expecting a diagnosis and some medicine.  Basically, the downvotes are because people think this is a poor question.  (But surely, you've been here long enough to know that ...)

Comment: ok close my queston, thnx @StephenC

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Job {
  private static final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0); 
  private final int jobID;
  private final String name;

  private boolean isFilled;

  public Job(String title){
    name = title;
    isFilled = false;
    jobID = count.incrementAndGet(); 
}
```

Comment: +1 for AtmicInteger (Multithreading was not mentioned, but it is always good to be Threadsafe)

Comment: Which final?  final AtomicInteger? it means that once count variable initialized it cannot be changed.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following,

```
public class TestIncrement {
private static int count = 0;
private int jobID;
private String name;

private boolean isFilled;

public TestIncrement(String title) {
    name = title;

    isFilled = false;
    setJobID(++count);
}

public int getJobID() {
    return jobID;
}

public void setJobID(int jobID) {
    this.jobID = jobID;
}
```

}

Please use following to test this

```
public class Testing {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        TestIncrement tst = new TestIncrement("a");
        System.out.println(tst.getJobID());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Job // Changed the classname to Job. Classes a written in CamelCasse Uppercase first in Java codeconvention
{
    private static int count = 0; 
    private int jobID;
    private String name;

    private boolean isFilled; // boolean defaults to false

    public Job(String title){ // Your code wan unable to compile here because of the ','
        name = title;
        isFilled = false;     // sets false to false
        jobID = ++count; 
    }
}
```

Your code will work, but you may get some problems, if you hit `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

It may be a better soltion to choose `long`. Or If you only need a Unique Identifier `UUID.randomUUID()`

Comment: Thanks, did not see that

Answer (score -1):

```
public class job
{
    private static int jobID;
    private String name;
    private boolean isFilled;

    public Job(String title){
        name = title;
        isFilled = false;

        synchronized {
            jobID = jobID + 1;
        } 
}
```