# Each instance of class 'Worker' should have an own id, starting at 1 and get incremented everytime (1, 2, 3 and so on)

Tags: class, kotlin, properties, instance, auto-increment

Question above. I have already tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24305983/16707725 but it doesn't work for me. Classes seem not to be able to memorize values.

```
fun main() {
  val worker = Worker("Frank")
  val worker2 = Worker("Elvis")
  println(worker.id)
  println(worker2.id)
}

class Worker(val name: String) {
  private val count: AtomicInteger = AtomicInteger(1)
  var id = count.incrementAndGet()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your property is a member of the class, so there is a new `count` property created and new AtomicInteger assigned for each instance of `Worker`. Your linked Java example is using a static field for the `count` so there is only one for all instances of the class. There are two ways to do this in Kotlin.

1. Top level property (defined outside the class) in the same file.

```
private val count: AtomicInteger = AtomicInteger(1)

class Worker(val name: String) {
    val id = count.incrementAndGet()
}
```

2. Put it in an `object`. A `companion object` is the typical choice for something like this. The `object` is shared by all instances of the class.

```
class Worker(val name: String) {

    companion object {
        private val count: AtomicInteger = AtomicInteger(1)
    }

    val id = count.incrementAndGet()
}
```

Comment: Very smooth answer, thank you for that!
The first way is what I tried at first but it didn't work because I named those two variables the same, I found out yet.